# Android Camera.Parameters setPictureSize not working

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to set the best possible output picture size in my camera object. So that, i can get a perfect downscaled sample image and display it.

During debugging i observed i am setting output picture size exactly the size of my screen dimensions. But when i `DecodeBounds` of the returned image by camera. I get some larger number!

**Also i am not setting my display dimensions as expected output picture size.** Code used to calculate and set the output picture size is given below.

**I am using this code for devices having API level < 21, so using camera shouldn't be a problem.**

I don't have any idea of why i am getting this behavior. Thanks in advance for help!

**Defining Camera parameter**

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
setOutputPictureSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), parameters); //update paramters in this function.

//set the modified parameters back to mCamera
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

**Optimal picture size calculation**

```
private void setOutputPictureSize(List<Camera.Size> availablePicSize, Camera.Parameters parameters)
{
    if (availablePicSize != null) {

        int bestScore = (1<<30); //set an impossible value.
        Camera.Size bestPictureSize = null;

        for (Camera.Size pictureSize : availablePicSize) {

            int curScore = calcOutputScore(pictureSize); //calculate sore of the current picture size
            if (curScore < bestScore) { //update best picture size
                bestScore = curScore;
                bestPictureSize = pictureSize;
            }
        }
        if (bestPictureSize != null) {
            parameters.setPictureSize(bestPictureSize.width, bestPictureSize.height);
        }
    }
}

//calculates score of a target picture size compared to screen dimensions.
//scores are non-negative where 0 is the best score.
private int calcOutputScore(Camera.Size pictureSize)
{
    Point displaySize = AppData.getDiaplaySize();
    int score = (1<<30);//set an impossible value.

    if (pictureSize.height < displaySize.x || pictureSize.width < displaySize.y) {
        return score;  //return the worst possible score.
    }

    for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {

        if (displaySize.x * i > pictureSize.height || displaySize.y * i > pictureSize.width) {
            break;
        }
        score = Math.min(score, Math.max(pictureSize.height-displaySize.x*i, pictureSize.width-displaySize.y*i));
    }
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue after many attempts!  Below are my findings:

**Step 1.** If we are already previewing, call `mCamera.stopPreview()`

**Step 2.** Set modified parameters by calling `mCamera.setParameters(...)`

**Step 3.** Start previewing again, call `mCamera.startPreview()`

If i call `mCamera.setParameters` without stopping preview (Assuming camera is previewing). Camera seems to ignore the updated parameters.

*I came up with this solution after several trail and errors. Anyone know better way to update parameters during preview please share.*

Comment: That's true, most of camera parameters cannot be changed while preview is live

Comment: I set my parameters during camera initialization before I call startPreview(). Still its not working.

Comment: Actually setPictureSize doesn't work for some devices at all